# How can i get my menu bar menu to close automatically when i click outside or on a link from it

Tags: javascript, html

`This is the html part

```
<nav class="navbar">
        <ul class="nav-menu">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
            </li>`your text`
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#services">Our services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

This is my js :

```
let menubar = document.querySelector('#menu-bars');
let mynav = document.querySelector('.navbar')



menubar.onclick = () =>{
    menubar.classList.toggle('fa-times');
    mynav.classList.toggle('active');
}`
```

I tried to understand the hamburger method but it wasn't really working .

Comment: You could use onmouseover and onclick https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

Comment: @Dean so basically if i use onmouseover it should hide of i don't have my pointer on it?